# routing issue on react app hosted on github

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a React app which has four routes, user,admin,home and bus. 
if I want to access `http://localhost:300/user` I was able to access that,
but after hosting it on Github( *https://loveyourtrip.tk/* ), if I want to access   *https://loveyourtrip.tk/user* , GitHub throws error status code 404.

However, I can log on  *https://loveyourtrip.tk/* . once I log on this URL, there is a button called "mange account". if you click there , you can see *user*. once clicked on user , you can go to `https://loveyourtrip.tk/user`. but I am not able to access it directly. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Currently gh-pages does not have routing support, but there are some workarounds listed in the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#notes-on-client-side-routing)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't handle the /user in the backend.
You can handle the whole thing from the front end by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter.
Or you can handle it from the backend by return the html page to all the routes.
Take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/hashrouter-demo